# How to add space in a string in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

how can i add space in this example string?

Input value in cell A1 is `ABCDEFGHIJK` and will be paste in another cell B1 with a format of `ABCDE FG HIJK`.

Comment: it depends do you always want it after the `E` or in place number 6?

Comment: ^^ or before the `F`? or in the middle?  or 3 characters after a `C`?  or ....?  (Oops - I just noticed that there are **two** spaces in the "output" string - so that means all my theories are wrong.)

Comment: Do you need a VBA solution or a formula?

Answer (score 0):

One formula to insert a space:
`=LEFT(A1,5)&" "&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-5)` to insert a space after the 5th position. (`ABCDE FGHIJK`)

One to insert 2 spaces as per example:
`=LEFT(A1,5)&" "&MID(A1,6,2)&" "&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-7)`
Input `ABCDEFGHIJK`, result `ABCDE FG HIJK`

In short: Use `=LEFT()`, `=RIGHT()` and `=MID()` to get parts of your string and concatenate the parts and your spaces.

**Edit:**
In VBA:

```
Public Function StringWithSpaces(inpStr As String) As String
    StringWithSpaces = Left(inpStr, 5) & " " & Mid(inpStr, 6, 2) & " " & Right(inpStr, Len(inpStr) - 7)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Rik thanks for the answer. What i need is the vba solution.

Comment: See Edit. It's the exact same in VBA as with regular formula's.